# What is a good utility for trimming .dv files without losing metadata?

Tags: editing, video-editor

I'm using a mac and I'd prefer a free utility, but don't mind using a commercial tool if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following ffmpeg command will remove the first and last minute of a ten-minute input file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:08:00 -c copy output.avi
```

`-ss` means start seek; that is, where the output will begin. `-t` means time; that is, the length of the output: so the above command will start at the first minute, and end eight minutes later.

With some video codecs, using these options with `-c copy` can cause issues due to I-frames (i.e. ffmpeg will cut to the nearest I-frame). This shouldn't be a problem with DV, though, sine AFAIK it's I-frame only.